# Ordering the input to an aggregate function

Tags: sql, netezza

Using a few SQL queries on our company Netezza box, I'm trying to concatenate a number of values into a single string. The hitch is that I need these values to be ordered, but Netezza won't let me order by terms that aren't grouped because it applies the ordering after doing the grouping.

I'm using a UDA called [group_concat](https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/W361a40e2ccf0_43c7_b802_e51fcadaec6b/page/C__%20UDX%20Examples) that concatenates strings and adds a separator between them. I'm pretty sure the UDA is functioning correctly (after tweaking it so it doesn't do any sorting internally).

Here's my test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST (GRP INTEGER, ID INTEGER, DATA VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,3,"Three");
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,1,"One");
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,2,"Two");
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,3,"Three");
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,2,"Two");
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,1,"One");
```

I want the following output:

- GRP: 1, ConcatData: "One,Two,Three"
- GRP: 2, ConcatData: "One,Two,Three"

Here's what I would have liked to do:

```sql
SELECT GRP, GROUP_CONCAT(DATA)
FROM TEST
ORDER BY ID
GROUP BY GRP;
```

but this is not possible: syntax error because group by must come before order by, and after doing that order by can only apply to terms that appear in the result set.

Others have suggested using a subselect to get around this: order in the subquery and group in the outer query like this:

```sql
SELECT GRP, GROUP_CONCAT(DATA,',') AS CONCATDATA
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM TEST
    ORDER BY GRP, ID
) AS X
GROUP BY GRP;
```

This appears to work in PostgreSQL 9.3 but not in Netezza. The order of the result changes each time I run the query.

The issue with this last query has nothing to do with the group by. It is the outer select that is ignoring the ordering of the inner select as illustrated by the following snippet:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM TEST
    ORDER BY GRP, ID
) AS X;
```

The inner select orders the results as expected, but the outer select reorders them arbitrarily (as far as I can tell).

So my questions are:

- Why is Netezza ignoring the ordering of my results?
- How can I build a string of grouped but ordered data?

PS: how should I include and format a result set in my question? I can't see how to make a table.

EDIT: Following @Alex 's comment, I've made it clear that I want to aggregate the values in one column (data) but order by another (id).

EDIT: I've realised that Netezza may not be able to order things in the same way as some other database engines because the data is distributed and worked on in parallel. The *Netezza UDF Developer's Guide* explains that in a UDA each SPU first aggregates the data in its possession, and then data from each SPU is merged centrally. In a simple UDA such as the ones I've looked at, the merge function knows nothing about what order the data should be in, and even if the data was ordered on each SPU, the final aggregated data cannot be guaranteed to be ordered. Maybe there's a way to write a UDA that accepts a ORDER BY clause... Alternatively, I could write a UDA that accepts two arguments, the first is the string to aggregate, the second is the order, however, I don't know that it's possible to easily work with associative arrays inside the UDA.

EDIT: [Niederee's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24435895/3776418) works so I've accepted it but I ended up creating the strings in PostgreSQL because we already had a PostgreSQL preprocessing phase before loading to Netezza. FYI this was to transform a list of vertex coordinates into a [WKT string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) that can be used in the Netezza Spatial Toolkit (similar to PostGIS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Even better solution.

```
SELECT 
    GRP, 
    CONCAT_DATA
FROM (
    SELECT 
        GRP,
        GROUP_CONCAT(data) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id ASC) concat_data,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM 
        test
) x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Note that this solution relies on using a very slightly modified group_concat UDX where the `sort` line has been removed.**

Earlier solution left for posterity:

Just found an reasonably compact solution but I'm not sure how robust it is to future changes in Netezza. By using an ordered window function to force ordering of the subquery, I seem to get results that are consistently in the correct order. Note that there is no explicit ordering of the results and the row number isn't used for anything but if you comment out `MAX(rn)` then the results are no longer ordered, presumably because the call to `row_number()` gets optimised away.

```
SELECT
    MAX(rn) as dummy, -- this prevents the row_number() from being optimised away and forces the output to be ordered
    GRP, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DATA,',') AS CONCATDATA
FROM
(
    SELECT GRP, ID, DATA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM TEST
) AS X
GROUP BY GRP;
```

Answer (score 1):

The not so simple way to do this, if you have the SQL Functions Toolkit installed would be to use `Arrays`.  I think a better way would be to add the group_concat UDF from IBM.  Array example below:

```
CREATE temp TABLE TEST (GRP INTEGER, ID INTEGER, DATA VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,3,'Three');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,1,'One');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,2,'Two');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,3,'Three');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,2,'Two');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,1,'One');


create temp table array_t(grp int,arr varchar(100));

-- create array placeholder
insert into array_t
select distinct  grp, sql_functions.admin.array(8) from test;

-- populate the array
update array_t a  set arr = sql_functions.admin.add_element(a.arr, b.data)
from (select grp, row_number() over(partition by grp order by id) as rown, data
from test) b
where a.grp=b.grp
and b.rown=1;

update array_t a  set arr = sql_functions.admin.add_element(a.arr, b.data)
from (select grp, row_number() over(partition by grp order by id) as rown, data
from test) b
where a.grp=b.grp
and b.rown=2;

update array_t a  set arr = sql_functions.admin.add_element(a.arr,b.data)
from (select grp, row_number() over(partition by grp order by id) as rown, data
from test) b
where a.grp=b.grp
and b.rown=3;
-- Return Result
select grp, sql_functions.admin.array_combine(arr,',')
from array_t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'd heard about the SQL Extensions Toolkit but didn't realise there was support for arrays. Without being able to test it right now, I haven't quite figured out why you populate the array in three stages and it looks like your `rown` is the same as my `id`. I hope to try out your solution later.

Comment: `rown` just makes sure that it is feed to the `array` in the right order

Answer (score 0):

This simple query seems to be doing what you want:

```
select grp, group_concat(id, ',')
from test
group by grp
order by grp;

 GRP | GROUP_CONCAT 
-----+--------------
   1 | 1,2,3
   2 | 1,2,3
(2 rows)
```

The documentation for `group_concat` says that it sorts the items regardless of the order they come in. The order is lexicographical, not numerical (it calls `sort()` method of `std::list<std::string>`). If you want custom ordering, you need to modify its c++ code.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Maybe I simplified my example too much. You're right that this will work but I really want to order on a different column from the one I concatenate. I'll see about amending my question.

Comment: I already modified `group_concat`, just commenting out `values.sort()`, so I assume that the values are concatenated in the order they arrive in. Maybe it could be modified further to accept two arguments, `data` and `id` but that's beyond me for now.